# Raku operator overloading

Tags: operator-overloading, raku

Using the following code:

```
use v6d;

# sub circumfix:<α ω>( @a ) {
#     @a[0] >= @a[1] & @a[0] <= @a[2];
# };

sub circumfix:<α ω>( $a, $b, $c ) {
    $a >= $b & $a <= $c;
};

if (α <5 0 10> ω) {
    say 'Truthy';
}
else {
    say 'Falsey';
}
```

Results in:

```
(base) hsmyers@BigIron:~/board$ perl6 ./op.p6
Too few positionals passed; expected 3 arguments but got 1
  in sub circumfix:<α ω> at ./op.p6 line 7
  in block <unit> at ./op.p6 line 11
```

Whereas switching the commented block for the other definition results in:

```
(base) hsmyers@BigIron:~/board$ perl6 ./op.p6
Truthy
```

The broken version (with three parameters) is the one I want, could someone explain why it is broken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<5 0 10>` literally constructs a [`List`](https://docs.raku.org/type/List), a *single* `List`.

An analogy would be a list of things to do, a todo list. How many things is a todo list? It's 1 -- one todo list.

Thus you get the error message:

> `expected 3 arguments but got 1`

What you want is to specify that you want *one* value that is itself made up of several values. Here's one way to do that:

```
sub circumfix:<α ω>( ( $a, $b, $c ) ) ...
```

The additional surrounding `(` and `)` cause [destructuring](https://docs.raku.org/type/Signature#Destructuring_arguments).

Comment: An alternative could be to use a slurpy signature `(*@foo where .elems == 3)` which could then support either `α $a, $b, $c ω` or `α ($a, $b, $c) ω`

Comment: @user0721090601 Sub-sigs also support either. Putting signature richness into sub-sigs gives the compiler more knowledge than a `where` clause so you get eg a nicer default error message and dispatch speed. I find `where` clauses best for arbitrary conditions that a sub-sig can't handle or for defining a fully custom error message (eg `( *@ where { .elems == 3 or die "nope" } )`). Note that you can combine these: `( *@ where { .elems == 3 or die "nope" } ($a, $b, $c) )` gives you destructuring into named variables when you get the right argument(s) and a custom error message when you don't.

Comment: ++ multi sigs would work to avoid the where, but I didn't realize one could use the anonymous one to destructure while providing for a where (I mean, I figured you *could* just never saw an example and it's really readable, actually)

Comment: Yes to `multi`s, much better than my suggestion of abusing a `where` clause for an error use case that can be be distinguished by multiple signatures without `where` clauses. (In retrospect I'm embarrassed at my revelation of my hackier instincts when they'd be so entirely unnecessary and inappropriate!) Anyhoo, have another upvote and thanks for improving our answer with your comments. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
D:\>6e "say <5 0 10>"
(5 0 10)
```

These aren't three arguments. It's a list of three values (of type `IntStr`) and therefore a single argument.